# Printing text with colour in C

Tags: c

I am making a simple game, and I want to print colored text in different situations for example the text ''You lost!'' would be red, or ''You won!'' would be green. This is what I have tried: `printf("\033[22;34mHello, world!\033[0m");` In this case what I see in my output is this `←[22;34mHello, world!←[0m`. Another thing I tried was this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ANSI_COLOR_RED     "\x1b[31m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_RESET   "\x1b[0m"

int main()
{
   printf(ANSI_COLOR_RED     "This text is RED!"     ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");
}
```

But in this situation I am getting a `←[31mThis text is RED!←[0m`
This is becoming a bit frustrating for me, how should I do this?

Comment: Color output is not portable, so in general the expectation should be that this will not work. It may work in special cases, though. You need to tell us what is the platform, how exactly do you run this program, and if it's Unix then what's the terminal (`echo "$TERM"`), and how you invoke the terminal (what exact application is it, i.e. is it xterm, Konsole, GNOME terminal, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems correct (aka it works on my machine), however, make sure  that the terminal in which you run it supports ANSI characters.